# How to add list of items to an ArrayList<String> in java?

Tags: java

I have list of words which I need to load to ArrayList< String >

**prefix.properties**

```
vocab\: = http://myweb.in/myvocab#
hydra\: = http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#
schema\: =  http://schema.org/
```

"vocab:" is actually "vocab:" .Slash(\) is used to read colon(:) character because it is special character.

**Dictionary.java**

```
public class Dictionary {
    public static ArrayList<String> prefix = new ArrayList<>();
    static {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;
        input = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("prefix.properties");
        System.out.println(input!=null);
        try {
            properties.load(input);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Set<Map.Entry<Object, Object>> entries = properties.entrySet();
        for(Map.Entry<Object, Object> E : entries)
        {
            prefix.add(E.getKey().toString());
            prefix.add(E.getValue().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**In Dictionary.java , ArrayList prefix will have**

```
prefix = [
           "vocab:",
           "http://myweb.in/myvocab#",
           "hydra:",
           "http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#",
           "schema:",
           "http://schema.org/"
         ]
```

**I am querying some data in another class.**
For eg:

```
public class QueryClass
{
    public ArrayList<String> queryResult(String findKey)
    {
       ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

       ArrayList<String> prefix = Dictionary.prefix;
       Iterator<String> iterator = prefix.iterator();

       while (iterator.hasNext())
       {
           String currentKey = iterator.next()+findKey;
           /**
               Here my logic to search data with this currentKey
           */
       }
       return result;
    }
}
```

**Problem :**
I want to avoid this method to load from .properties file because there is possibility of odd number of elements can be present while .properties file provide (key,value) pair way to store data.

Reason why I have to load from separate file ? Because In future I will have to add more keywords/String thats why I put it in prefix.properties file.

Is there any alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Do not re-invent the wheel.

If you can define the file format, then just go for java properties.

You see, the Properties class has a method [getProperty(String, String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) where the second argument can be used to pass a **default** value for example. That method could be used in order to fetch keys that don't come with values.

I would be really careful about inventing your own format; instead I would look into ways of re-using what is already there. Writing code is similar to building roads: people forget that each new road that is built translates to maintenance efforts in the future.

Besides: you add string values to a list of strings by calling `list.add(strValue)`. That is all that is to that.

Edit on your comment: when "java properties" are not what you are looking for; then consider using **other** formats. For example you could be persisting your data in some **JSON** based format. And then just go for some existing JSON parser. Actually, your data almost looks like JSON already.

Comment: Actually I don't want Properties file.My requirement is there should be separate file which will have list of words and at run time these list of words load into "ArrayList<String> prefix" in QueryClass.java class.Reason why I want to store separately? because these list of words used by other classes also. So can I do it with simple text file or any other way?

Comment: JSON format can handle this thing but I think my problem seems more simple for that I don't think I should go with JSON.[See this] (https://ideone.com/8GzShi) Only difference , In this code the list of words are in a single String and in Java class function but I want to keep this in separate file because I will have to add some more words to list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need to use ArrayList but if you want to pass these property keys/values, there are 2 better ways:

1. Use Properties itself.
2. Convert to HashMap.